# Are there any smart contract templates?

Tags: dapps, dapp-development, template

I'm looking for one or more possibly open source Ethereum smart contracts that have been tested and perform some useful use case.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for something like [OpenZeppelin contracts](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts) (implementations of tested libraries/contracts to build contracts).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was seeking. +1. If there are any other open source libraries anyone else knows about, that would be greatly appreciated also.

Comment: That library doesn't really make sense. It's just a list of folders filled with code with no explanation. is it accompanied with some sort of guide walk-through documentation